# ZUUL ROUTING FOR SPRING WEB SERVICES

Tags: spring, web-services, netflix-zuul

I have a monolithic backend system interacting via soapws. The implementation is done via the spring ws. UI client also communicates via soap. All i need is to build a router and throttler sitting between UI and the endpoints. We intend to use zuul as the router and the guava throttler. Can anyone help me with a sample. I tried the way spring zuul routing given in git. however the router cannot find the backend webservices. 1 more thing I need to deploy both the router and the webservices in J2ee containers.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: any updates on this?